# Change url_suffix dynamically

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

Is it possible? If I set `$config['url_suffix'] = '/en';` in the file `config.php` itself everything is ok.

However if I want to set it like so: `$ci->config->set_item('url_suffix', '/en');` in my hook class:

```
class Language_loader {

    public function __construct() 
    {

    }

    public function initialize() 
    {   
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->db = $ci->load->database('english', TRUE);
        $ci->config->set_item('url_suffix', '/en');
    }

}
```

then it doesn't work! I get `404 Page Not Found`. Oh, and hook is set up properly I tested with the above change of database.
Hook config in `hooks.php`:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'Language_loader',
    'function' => 'initialize',
    'filename' => 'Language_loader.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

EDIT: Some more info I noticed, application redirects links properly with `/en` suffix its just when I get there instead of the site I get 404. So I guess it works but only half of it.

EDIT2: I can't set `$this->config->set_item('url_suffix', '/en');` anywhere for that matter I tried various location throughout the script. I can set other variables in config file but not this `url_suffix` one. If I only knew when in the excecution codeigniter reads that value I could change it.

Comment: I suspect that your controllers expect one more argument in methods.

Comment: Not the case, like I said method is run properly

Comment: You can remove leading slash from suffix string. Is there valid page load if `index.php` is used in URL? Put your code from `initialize()` method to `__construct()` method and comment `initialize()` out.

Comment: If I remove trailing slash my URLs look like `sitename/admin/home/loginen` instead of `sitename/admin/home/login/en` still getting the 404 though even if I add `index.php`. Can't add the code in the constructor hooks don't work this way

Comment: Try `pre_system` or `pre_controller` hook point.

Comment: I did try it and the problem there is I cant get the instance `$ci =& get_instance();` because the controller isn't loaded yet

Comment: Have you considered setting config item in `MY_Controller` or some core class instead of hook?

Comment: I did. Look at my edited question.

Comment: Check [this](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/how_codeigniter_works) link and compare with v3.